# Installing Ubuntu on Mac

Tags: dual-boot, mac, macosx

I am installing Ubuntu on a Macbook Pro. I don't like using reefit, I like booting into a default operating system I configure.

So I installed Ubuntu to a partition I created from osx, set first file system (in drop down it had a 4 in it) then I set mount to / the drop down at the bottom I set to my hard drive I installed it on.

When I boot osx and hold option I'm not given the option to boot Ubuntu. Is there some terminal commands I can run in osx (maybe this is something Apple decided I should not be able to do through the GUI).

I just want to install it without reefit.

Answer (score 0):

I've installed Ubuntu on my macbook in a similar fashion and after rebooting, my macbook boots into the Ubuntu grub menu by default.

Then, I disabled the grub menu from appearing on boot by editing my grub configuration file so that my macbook just boots immediately into Ubuntu.

Try rebooting without holding the option key and seeing which environment the machine boots into. If it boots into OS X, plug back in the Ubuntu USB (assuming you used a bootable USB to install) and boot into the live environment. Then, install efibootmgr and adjust the current boot order of the macbook so that it boots into Ubuntu by deafult.

Hope this helps!